# Limit of continuous function in a complete space

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

Consider a complete metric space $(M,d)$ and a continuous function $h:(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (M,d)$. Prove that "$\lim_{x\rightarrow a+}h(x)$" exists in the sense that we can find $m\in M$ such that $(\forall\epsilon >0)(\exists \delta>0)(\forall x\in (a,a+\delta))h(x)\in B(m,\epsilon)$ with the obvious notation of $B(m,\epsilon)$ being the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $m$.

Comment: What is the relation between f and h?

Comment: My bad- it's h.

Comment: Do we have $a < 0 < b$? How do we know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} h(x)$ is well defined? Is it possible that $(a,b)=(0,1)$? Or should it be $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}$?

Comment: Right, it should be $a+$. As for the limit $m$, it doesn't seem like it needs to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.

Consider $(a,b)=(0,1)$ and $M=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. The function $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous, but there is no limit in $\mathbb{R}$.

It is false even if $M$ is assumed to be compact: again $f\colon(0,1)\to[-1,1]$, $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ is a counterexample.

Note that the condition you use is *precisely* the definition of limit when $M$ is $\mathbb{R}$ (or a subspace thereof) with the usual metric.

Comment: You are absolutely right in both examples that there is no real limit, and in fact the term "limit" is misleading: We are to show that $(\forall\epsilon >0)(\exists \delta>0)(\forall x\in (0,\delta))h(x)\in B(m,\epsilon)$. Upvoted anyhow.

Comment: @ProblemsInAnalysis That's meaningless; it should be $\forall x\in(a,a+\delta)$, but the statement is false nonetheless. The two counterexamples of course stand, because that's the definition of limit and, since in the two cases the limit doesn't exist, they're good.

Comment: You are right on both and question fixed - the "limit" is only indicative as notation. The question stands, in the sense we are to find one point m that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: @ProblemsInAnalysis And I showed you that you generally cannot.

Comment: That you did, and would upvote the answer if I could. Still cannot make out of what the author of the question had in mind. Bare with me.